# Which of these two is correct, “What should everyone know?” or “What everyone should know?”

Tags: questions, interrogatives, free-relative-clauses, subject-auxiliary-inversion

Which of the above is correct usage and why. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2628672/revisions) edit in a stackoverflow question and it got me wondering why was it edited. Is it just because the first one sounds better?

Answer (score 0):

> Everyone should know something.
>
> What should everyone know?

Asking the question to the object of the sentence we usually use inversion after the question word.

Comment: Would you care to explain in further. I didn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

The source of confusion here is that on online forums the title of a question can be perceived (by the poster) more as a title (or rubric) than as a question posed.

If we pose the question:

**What should every programmer know?**

If we create a rubric beneath which we list all the things a  programmer should know:

**Things every programmer should know**

**What every programmer should know**